# Why are religious tensions and communal tensions on the rise in India?

Tags: india

Recently the [Nupur Sharma case](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-61716241) and [arrests against those threatening Nupur](https://www.google.com/search?q=nupur%20sharma&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjujoPNxu34AhUxoVwKHQHsCfYQ_AUoAnoECAIQBA&biw=1710&bih=876&dpr=1.6), and, the [Tailor beheading case](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/6/30/thousands-protest-in-indias-udaipur-after-hindu-tailor-murdered), it makes me believe that Communal/ Relegious violence have been rising a lot as of late. Could reasons be given for why this is happening?

Comment: Not sure if a few examples are evidence enough for a trend. Maybe ask first for a more sounds statistical basis before asking for the reasons why. Are tensions really substantially rising in India?

Comment: @Trilarion For some historical numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_violence_in_India#Statistics I suppose data up to 2019 might be avaialable too (it seems the MHA takes 2-3 years to publish those figures).

Comment: @Fizz Data seems to suggest that tensions are kind of on a steady more or less constant level over the last years if the reporting rate stayed the same and the uncounted cases aren't too high.

Comment: The clout generated by such incidences has increased because of rise in the penetration of social media in the country and the mainstream media also mentions these more frequently than earlier. It gives that perception of "rise" but as the stats above show, it hasn't really increased. Plus, overall population increase might contribute as well.